# Calculate time out for items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to be able to determine the average number of days and item was checked out.  I am trying to count the number of times an itemrecord was borrowed and the number of days it was borrowed for each occurrence.
The data looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE project (
    transnum int,
    transdate datetime,
    transtype int,
    itemrecord int,
    collection int
);

INSERT INTO project (transnum,transdate,transtype,itemrecord,collection) 
VALUES

(1, '2018-01-02 12:15:00.000', 6001, 3617581, 1), 
(3, '2018-01-09 14:17:01.000', 6001, 3617581, 1),
(7, '2018-01-14 09:11:15.000', 6002, 3617581, 1),
(9, '2018-02-02 12:15:00.000', 6001, 3617581, 1),
(12, '2018-02-09 10:50:00.000', 6002, 3617581, 1),
(15, '2018-02-11 09:17:10.000', 6001, 3617581, 1),
(16, '2018-02-18 15:01:35.000', 6001, 3617581, 1),
(20, '2018-02-20 08:54:00.000', 6002, 3617581, 1),
(22, '2018-02-22 15:21:16.000', 6001, 3617581, 1),
(23, '2018-02-23 13:15:00.000', 6001, 3677214, 2),
(25, '2018-02-25 17:21:00.000', 6002, 3677214, 2);
```

The itemrecords get checked out (6001) and then checked in (6002) but there is also the possibility for the item to be renewed (also a 6001) before it gets checked back in.

So, for example itemrecord 3617581 was checked out 5 times (checkout on 2-22 not counted because there is no final check in (6002) in the scope of the report) so the average checkout for collection 1 would be 28/5 or 5 Days.

```
itemrecord Daysout Collection
3617581,   7       1
3617581,   5       1
3617581,   7       1
3617581,   7       1
3617581,   2       1
```

[SQL Fiddler for Data Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19445)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: ...because when it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split the data based on the 6002s.  Then take the earliest 6001.  The way to do this is a reverse, condition, cumulative sum:

```
select itemrecord, 
       min(case when transtype = 6001 then transdate end) as date_6001,
       max(case when transtype = 6002 then transdate end) as date_6002,
       datediff(day, 
                min(case when transtype = 6001 then transdate end),
                max(case when transtype = 6002 then transdate end)
               ) as diff
from (select p.*,
             sum(case when transtype = 6002 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by itemrecord order by transdate desc) as grp
      from project p
     ) p
group by itemrecord, grp;
```

This provides the timing for each "segment".  If you want the total, then make this a subquery/CTE and add another layer of aggregation.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that gets me very close.  How can the average for the collection be calculated now that the diff is calcuated?